# AFNetworking : Image is not uploading pre iOS 8

Tags: ios, afnetworking, image-uploading

I'm using `AFNetworking` in my app to make possible client-server communication. Its working great. But today, our tester encounter an issue, that we can't upload an image to the server on device which having iOS 7.0. and 7.1. (Note: we're targeting app from iOS 7.0. >= versions) We've encountered this on simulator as well.

Have someone ever encounter this before? I'm not posting the code as its working with iOS 8 and later versions. So I'm sure, there's no issue with the code. However, I think, the issue may inside `AFNetworking` framework?

PS.

- We're using latest version of `AFNetworking` framework.
- All other API calls working fine in both of the iOS versions.
- I'm using `AFHTTPSessionManager` to call my API.  (Available from iOS 7.0.)

Please help!

Let me know, if you want more info. on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this code:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"photo.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];

[op start];
```

Comment: Strange but it worked with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. And not with `AFHTTPSessionManager`. I've up voted your answer but would not going to accept it as I want an actual reason for this. Thanks though!

Comment: You should post your code, you are using with AFHTTPSessionManager to find out the reason of non uploading the image

Comment: There's no need of posting my code as its working under iOS 8 and above and not below version. `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` approach work in all iOS versions but as `AFNetworking` suggested from iOS 7 and above we should use `AFHTTPSessionManager`.